# Rewrite URLs on Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, nginx, url-rewriting, lumen, homestead

I'm making a web game. The backend is Lumen and the frontend is a single page application. I want to make a use of JavaScript History API, so all URIs (except for actual file or directory paths) should point to the same backend script. I know how to do it on Apache, but my local server is Laravel Homestead, which is nginx.

If it was Apache, I would put this to `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Is there any built-in rewrite functionality in Laravel Homestead? If not, how can I achieve the same effect on nginx?

Comment: On `nginx`, that functionality is usually achieved using `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;`

Comment: I don't think nginx config should be edited directly on Homestead.